# Token value changes on page reload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Why is my token value changing on page reload in laravel 5.2?
Hence session does not persist, it returns only token.

```
return Session::all();
```

Comment: Do you refer to csrf token?

Comment: If you referring CSRF token, then yes, it changes on every refresh/reload for security reason. what issue your are facing ? Please explain more

Comment: i am not able to get session on controller after redirect from one controller

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected, tha token is meant to work this way.

If your Session does not persiste check your session driver in your settings (eg. In your `.env` file) and male sure you have given write permission on `storage` to web user.

You may try to call session through its helper with something like `session()->get('my_session_key')`. If that works, you may have forgot to reference `use Session;` before class declaration to import the namespace.

Comment: phaberest thanks for rply
im using file driver ,have given write permission to  storage,it works fine in local environment but make problem in live

Comment: removing csrf can cause any problem because i removed it from kernel and not removed from form.

Comment: Not sure about it. Why did you disable it, anyway? Do you get a specific error? Have you tried to `dd(session())`?

Comment: it return same,only token not other data .

array:1 [▼
  "_token" => "Ga9xYTsqLE6dkHWp0fQI3ZqgN2onoIV9FjNkD4gp"
]

Comment: Try to switch session driver with `array` just for testing

Comment: Let me also see how you're setting your session variables updating your question

Comment: I can't be sure you imported the `Session` namespace, so try to use `$request->session()->put('key', 'value');` or `session(['key' => 'value']);` to store data in session